# "Warning Master Merge operation was not done..." What to do?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing

Have anyone encountered this error message in the SQL server log?

> Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 56, objid
>   286624064, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext
>   catalog reorganize.

No other errors are recorded.

The effects are that the full text catalog takes several hours to rebuild on a newly created database (very little data in it). It renders the full-text feature literally unusable...

It is fresh installation on a Windows Server 2008 R2 and the SQL server:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2012
>   20:23:12      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Nothing else is installed on the server.

I have browsed google - nothing found. Even the Microsoft documentation does not mention this error.

**Update:**
The error message appears numerous times in the event log. Each time when when the catalog is updated. This message is not a translation from other message. It is in English. Here is another sample of it:

2013-05-22 17:53:39.27 spid70s     Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 89, objid 565577053, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext catalog reorganize.

2013-05-22 17:53:39.27 spid257s    Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 89, objid 539148966, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext catalog reorganize.

2013-05-22 17:53:39.30 spid343s    Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 89, objid 667149422, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext catalog reorganize.

2013-05-22 17:53:39.30 spid135s    Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 89, objid 603149194, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext catalog reorganize.

Here is more information about the database:

1. The database have been created after the SQL server was installed. It was not a restore from a database created on another version of the SQL server.
2. The database have one full-text catalog. This full-text catalog is the default.
3. The database have about 300 tables. Each table have one or two columns with full-text index enabled.
4. Each table in the database have up to 10 records in it.
5. Because such databases are created with code, I have the ability to create them on different SQL servers. When such database is created on SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2, there is no errors in the log and the full-text re-index them for up to a second. (Eg. It works with the other versions of the SQL server, not on SQL 2012).

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you give a few more details then someone may be able to help. You didn't mention *when* the error occurs, e.g. randomly, after restoring a database or at some other time. I also suspect that you've translated the error from another language, which is good but it would be helpful to have the original error number and text too. And you said that it takes a long time to "rebuild" your FTS catalog, are you using `REBUILD` or `REORGANIZE` as the error says, and have you tried both? Have you also tried dropping and re-creating the catalog completely?

Comment: @Pondlife, here is the exact copy of the error message:
2013-05-22 17:53:40.40 spid191s    Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 89, objid 1659868980, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext catalog reorganize. 
2013-05-22 17:53:40.40 spid50s     Warning Master Merge operation was not done for dbid 89, objid 1659152956, so querying index will be slow. Please run alter fulltext catalog reorganize. 
... And this goes on and on. I will extend the description of the question.

Comment: We have similar issue with SQL Server 2014. But it's even worse - SQL Server stops receiving any connections. And we see "Deadlocked Schedulers" message in log. To be investigated.